# NServiceBus timeout polling happens too often

Tags: azure, nservicebus

My NServiceBus endpoint is polling for timeouts multiple times per second even when I have set TimeoutPersisterReceiver's property SecondsToSleepBetweenPolls to 10 seconds or even a minute. Any idea why this can happen and how to prevent this?

My endpoint is running on Azure Service Bus transport and uses Tables storage for persistence.

At the time I have ~5 scheduled tasks and each of them are configured to run in 1-2 minute intervals.

Comment: are you sure you are not getting an exception occurring and the action is being retried?